# Why I cannot type cast with (Point2d.Double)? - Java

Tags: java, casting, classcastexception

I have below code snippet - Which **doesn't work**.

```
private void startAddingTrackPointValue()
    {
        Set<Point2D.Double> keySet = this.trackPointList.keySet();
        Point2D.Double[] keys = (Point2D.Double[]) keySet.toArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(keys[i]);
        }
    }
```

Which generates **exception is**, This...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.awt.geom.Point2D$Double;
    at SegmentFactory.startAddingTrackPointValue(SegmentFactory.java:170)
    at SegmentFactory.<init>(SegmentFactory.java:44)
    at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:8)
```

But this **works fine**, If I do it like this,

```
private void startAddingTrackPointValue()
    {
        Set<Point2D.Double> keySet = this.trackPointList.keySet();
        Object[] keys = (Object[]) keySet.toArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(keys[i]);
        }
    }
```

Question is, **why can't I typecast with Point2D.Double[]?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a typed array to `toArray()`:

```
Point2D.Double[] keys = keySet.toArray(new Point2D.Double[keySet.size()]);
```

Answer (score 3):

because "Object[]" is not an instance of "Point2D.Double[]".

neither of these will work:

```
Point2D.Double[] = (Point2D.Double[])new Object[0]; // this is essentially what your code is doing
Point2D.Double = (Point2D.Double)new Object();
```

do this instead:

```
Point2D.Double[] keys = (Point2D.Double[]) keySet.toArray(new Point2D.Double[keySet.size()]);
```

Comment: Partially correct, However "new" keyword is required in .toArray argument :). Thanks

Comment: @SkeetOverFlow - sorry, i was typing fast.

Comment: A convenience constructor would have been nice.